# How to Create Managed Property on Custom Content Type Column

Tags: search, managed-metadata, managed-property

I created a custom content type with a number of columns.  How can I create a Metadata Property for Search based on a column in this custom content type?  How would I map the crawled properties (or to what)?  My plan is to create a managed property, so I can reference it in my refinement panel.

Thanks for any help provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to answer this question from this article:
http://blogs.pointbridge.com/Blogs/tseng_william/Pages/Post.aspx?_ID=11

Comment: And this is why its important to actually add your answer instead of just linking an article. That link is dead.